# How can i add/substract integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

```
#first block: calculating last purchase date 
from datetime import timedelta
last_purchase_date = (sales_data['TRANSAC_DATE'].max())  + timedelta(days=1)


print("Last purchase Date: ", sales_data['TRANSAC_DATE'].max())
print("Recency/Last purchase Date: ", last_purchase_date)



#Second block: calculating Recency of last purchase in RFM analysis
RFM = sales_data.groupby(['CLIENT_ID']).agg({
    'CLIENT_ID': lambda x: (last_purchase_date - x.max()).days,
    'Transaction_ID': 'count',
    'NET': 'sum'
})

#Error line: lambda x: (last_purchase_date - x.max()).days

RFM.rename(columns={'CLIENT_ID': 'Recency', 'Transaction_ID': 'Frequency', 'NET': 'MonetaryValue'}, inplace= True)
display(RFM)
```

**Problem:** i want to have the recency in days but i cant subtract the output x.max() which in array of intergers from last_purchase_date (timestamp)
**#Error line:** lambda x: (last_purchase_date - x.max()).days
**#Error msg:** *Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`*

Comment: You must provide a [mre], i.e. all code and example data needed for us to be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your limited question, What I understand is - `sales_data` is your `DataFrame` and `last_purchase_date` is `timestamp`, If my understanding is right, try this:

```
import pandas as pd

last_purchase_date = pd.Timestamp(last_purchase_date)
def calculate_recency(x):
    return (last_purchase_date - x.max()).days

RFM = sales_data.groupby(['CLIENT_ID']).agg({
    'CLIENT_ID': calculate_recency,
    'Transaction_ID': lambda x: len(x),
    'NET': 'sum'
})

RFM.rename(columns={'CLIENT_ID': 'Recency', 'Transaction_ID': 'Frequency', 'NET': 'MonetaryValue'}, inplace=True)

display(RFM)
```